# LinkedList Nodes

Tags: java, dictionary, linked-list, nodes

I have a question about an assignment that i am being required to complete. 
Write a menu driven program that either accepts words and their meanings, or displays the list of words in lexicographical order (i.e. as in a dictionary). When an entry is to be added to the dictionary you must first enter the word as one string, and then enter the meaning as separate string. A word may have more than one meaning, and may be entered at separate times. When this occurs, place each successive meaning on a separate line. This new meaning must be preceded by a dash. For example, if you enter the following words and with their meanings in the following order: Library, School, Cup, and School, then your output should be a display as shown in the Figure 1.

Use the concept of linked list to carryout this exercise. You will need at minimum the following classes: 
•   A WordMeaning class that hold the name of a word and its meaning.
•   A WordMeaningNode class that creates the node of information and its link field.
•   A WordList class that creates and maintain a linked list of words and their meanings. 
•   A Dictionary class that test your classes.

The question concerns the second bullet. I am not sure about how to go about creating a constructor for WordMeaningNode. This is what I have so far:

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;
public class WordMeaningNode 


{
  String information;
  WordMeaningNode locale;




  public WordMeaningNode(WordMeaning data) 
//WordMeaning is a class that takes two strings(Word and definition) and stores it.
//Entry is a method that returns the strings stored in WordMeaning.

  {
      information = data.Entry();
      locale = null;
  }

  public String getMeaning()

  {
      return information;
  }

  public WordMeaningNode getNext()

  {
      return locale.getNext();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

First, I think you would be better passing in the String that results from data.entry(). That was you can create your constructors in the following manner:

```
public WordMeaningNode(String entry){
   int index = entry.indexOf(',') + 1; //Assuming your String is comma delimited.
   information = entry.substring(0, index);
   String next = entry.substring(index);
   if(next.isEmpty()){
      locale = null;
   } else {
      locale = new WordMeaningNode(next);
   }
}
```

Second, is your getNext() method working correctly? It seems like that would always give a null pointer exception.

Good luck!